# Why did US junk bond funds fall from mid 2014 thru early 2016?

Tags: bonds, junk-bonds

The Federal Funds rate was 0% the whole time, and the Prime rate stayed at 3.75%, so it seems that investor fear was the cause.

What caused them to be afraid?

Here shows how two big junk bond ETFs fell in that time frame:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What data are you looking at? I show the [S&P High-yield index](https://us.spindices.com/indices/fixed-income/sp-500-high-yield-corporate-bond-index) was roughy flat between June 2014 and feb 2016.

Comment: @DStanley question edited. Images pasted showing their performance in that range.